# Least Squares Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

If $$\mathbf{\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_N
\end{bmatrix}} = \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
b_{N1} & b_{N2} & b_{N3}
\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{\begin{bmatrix}
K_1 \\
K_2 \\
K_3
\end{bmatrix}}+\mathbf{\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 \\
e_2 \\
\vdots \\
e_N
\end{bmatrix}}\tag{1}$$ then K can be found as \begin{equation}
K = (B'B)^{-1}B'Y
\tag{2}\end{equation}
however B is unknown and is a function of $
e_{n}(t-t_{d})
$
The only known parameter that I have is $e_{n}(t)$.
It is mentioned in the article that I am reading that $t_{d}$ can be found by letting $S=e'e$ and then partial differentiating S as $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t_d}=0$$
However, this doesn't make sense to me. Because from my reading, that is how the normal equation (2) is derived.
I would be grateful if someone can guide me in finding $t_d$ and I apologize if the question seems too noobish as I do not have a strong mathematical background. I have been reading on linear equations for a while but I haven't yet encountered a similar question.
Thank you

Comment: Given your background, I recommend you use a math or statistics package which has linear least squares capability, and which allows you to enter the problem in a "natural" way. The package will then take care of the details under the hood, and provide you the solution and any diagnostic information.

Comment: I will get back about this in detail. I think I read somewhere that equation of form $e(t-td)$ can be expanded to approximate according to taylor series expansion. I believe it then becomes a differential equation and there may be a way to solve delay differential equation. I am still looking into it.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: I doubt differential equations, delay or otherwise, are involved in this.